# Quartz XML - Single Trigger, Multiple Jobs, Job-Data-Map

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Having an issue with a simple quartz configuration that will just not work for me. I have a simple "HitUrl" job, and I'd like to create two triggers in xml which pass different URLs into the job. Unfortunately when trying to access the passed value in the Job (in Java), null is returned.

**XML Configuration**

```
<job-scheduling-data
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd"
    version="1.8">

    <schedule>

        <!-- Executes Hit URL Standard Job -->
        <job>
            <name>HitURL</name>
            <group>DEFAULT</group>
            <job-class>standardjobs.HitUrl</job-
        </job>

        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>HitFirstURL</name>
                <group>DEFAULT</group>
                <job-name>HitURL</job-name>                
                <job-data-map>
                    <entry>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <value>itworked</value>
                    </entry>
                </job-data-map>                   
                <cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>                
            </cron>
        </trigger>

    </schedule>

</job-scheduling-data>
```

**Java Code**

```
package standardjobs;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HitUrl implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("================= HIT URL EXECUTING ======================="); 

        //Retrieve the URL keypair from the job data map
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();        
        String url = jobDataMap.getString("url");

        System.out.println("Hitting url "+url); //Just says "Hitting url: null"

    }

}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to extract the URL parameter value from the JobDetail's job data map in a situation when you have actually defined the parameter on the trigger level.

You should use the getMergedJobDataMap method defined in the passed JobExecutionContext instance. See the relevant [JobExecutionContext JavaDoc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getMergedJobDataMap%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply Jan - you were definitely along the correct lines. I fixed it by changing the java code as follows:

**Old Code**

```
JobDataMap jobDataMap = ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
```

**New Code**

```
JobDataMap jobDataMap = ctx.getTrigger().getJobDataMap();
```

Comment: If Jan Moravec's reply was correct and helped you solve your problem, then why didn't you accept their answer?